# align webparts within two different webpartzones

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server

I've googled for lots of forum on webpart alignment and understand it can be achieved using -

a. Orientation: Horizontal (applicable in case of 2 webpart added to
    the same webpart zone)

b. DIV ID (via CSS, adding the width)

However, in my case performing either doesn't works and need expert view.

Requirement:
Webpart placed in WebpartZone 3 & 4, to be align to each other rather appearing one below.

Please check the WebpartZone code -

```
                <div class="row" id="homeRow4">
                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Row4" ID="WebPartZone4"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                </div>
```

Please suggest what change shall I make in order for the webpart added to HomeROW3 is align on left and allows webpart of HomeROW4 to be align next to it with align as right?

Comment: Are you working on custom page or SharePoint page?

Comment: SharePoint Page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text layout of SharePoint page. Edit page, select layout `Two columns` from `Ribbon >> Format Text >> Text Layout`. You can add HomeROW3 to left zone and HomeROW4 to right zone.